# Calculate day number from date function fg: no job control

Tags: bash, shell, unix, osx-yosemite

I have a function to calculate day number based on three parameters **d,m,y**

this is the function

```
function getDate (){
    d=$1
    m=$2
    y=$3
    m=$((m+9)) % 12
    y=$((y - m/10))
    return $((365*y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + (m*306 + 5)/10 + ( d - 1 )))
}
```

Call for example :

```
getDate 01 01 2015
```

The problem is I get always `line 8: fg: no job control` which is this line `m=$((m+9)) % 12`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
m=$((m+9)) % 12
```

by

```
m=$(((m+9)%12))
```

Use `$((expression))` for calculations.

---

`return` can only return values from 0 to 255. In your case I suggest to replace `return` by `echo`.